# Why does the linux GIC (interrupt) driver only allow rising-edge and level-high triggers?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

The linux [gic driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.14.79/source/drivers/irqchip/irq-gic.c#L203) limits the trigger configuration to only allow rising-edge and level-high triggers. Is there a good reason that they did not include falling-edge and level-low events?

Comment: Did you look into the corresponding data sheet?

Comment: @0andriy That is a generic drive that corresponds to a bunch of different processors

Comment: Still same question.

Comment: Likely this is intended to operate on internal virtual signals, and anything coming from the outside world active-low would need to be inverted at a lower I/O level.  Some support for that idea is found in for example https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/4/3/285